# Does Android 13 Treat the video and image permissions the same?

Tags: android-permissions, android-13

Android 13 has a new feature known as “Granular Media Permissions” (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions).

My team and I are trying to make sure we request the right permissions for an android app that can (in two different workflows) utilize a user’s photos or a user’s videos.  So we’ve written some code to request the new READ_MEDIA_VIDEO permission for the video workflow and code to request the new READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission for the photo workflow.

What I am confused about is why does the app’s settings page still show only one permission under “App permissions” (Photos and videos)?  Shouldn’t it show two permissions — one for photos and one for videos?

Similarly when the user actually sees a permission dialog when we request one of the two permissions, the dialog simply gives the user the option to grant the “Photos and videos” permission.  If the permissions are supposed to be granular but they both grant the same privilege to the app I am not clear on what the benefit is of this new feature.

So far Google’s docs on this have not be very clear on this either.  Although the page linked does indicate that if the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VIDEO permissions are requested at the same time only one dialog appears we are not actually doing this.  We request one of the two permissions, not both.  However both permissions ARE listed in the android manifest.  Could this be a factor?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have also faced same issue and confused about usage, can you please let me know in case you found any solution. thanks.